# Any advantage to using variable with tilde in javascript vs. -1?

Tags: javascript, tilde

Other than a slight performance gain, is there an advantage to using !~x as true vs. checking to see if ~-1 ?

Comment: `if (~someString.indexOf(someOtherString)){...}` is nice, but not always clear.

Comment: `~1` is `-2`, `~~X` can be used to do a 'floor' on `X` (where X is positive)

Comment: What do you mean by _"checking to see if ~-1"_? Is your question `~x` vs `x != -1`?

Answer (score 3):

There can be a difference for large numbers. Because you're confined to a 32-bit range, consider the following.

```
var x = Math.pow(2,32)-1; // 4294967295

console.log(~x); // 0
```

So here you get a `0` result giving you the opposite boolean conversion than you'd expect.

Comment: Still not sure if this answers the question, because I'm not sure what the question actually is. :(

Comment: @Shmiddty: I'm pretty sure your comment under the question describes what the asker is getting at. But if this is an Array or Array-like collection that can have very high indices, there can be an unexpected results.

Comment: I definitely +1'd this because it's a good thing to note.

Answer (score 0):

There's no behavioral difference. Use whichever is clearest for the scenario you're implementing.